# How to template creating a map for custom types

Tags: c++, dictionary, templates, lambda

In my code I have a number of places where I need to take an std::vector of things and put it into a std::map indexed by something.  For example here are two code snippets:

```
//sample A

    std::map<Mode::Type, std::vector<Mode>> modesByType;
    for( const auto& mode : _modes ) {
      Mode::Type type = mode.getType();
      auto it = modesByType.find( type );
      if( it == modesByType.end() ) {
        std::vector<Mode> v = { mode };
        modesByType.insert( std::pair( type, v ) );
      } else {
        it->second.push_back( mode );
      }
    }

//sample B

  std::map<unsigned, std::vector<Category>> categoriesByTab;
  for( const auto& category : _categories ) {
    unsigned tabIndex = category.getTab();
    auto it = categoriesByTab.find( tabIndex );
    if( it == categoriesByTab.end() ) {
      std::vector<Category> v = { category };
      categoriesByTab.insert( std::pair( tabIndex, v ) );
    } else {
      it->second.push_back( category );
    }
  }
```

I'd like to generalize this and create a template function like:

```
template<typename T, typename V>
std::map<T,std::vector<V>> getMapByType( const std::vector<V>& items, ?? ) {
  std::map<T,std::vector<V>> itemsByType;
  for( const auto& item : items ) {
    unsigned index = ??;
    auto it = itemsByType.find( index );
    if( it == itemsByType.end() ) {
      std::vector<V> v = { item };
      itemsByType.insert( std::pair( index, v ) );
    } else {
      it->second.push_back( item );
    }
  }
  return itemsByType;
}
```

My question is, how do I define the ?? argument to this function so that I can call the correct V.foo() function to get the index value for the map?

Note, I do not want to make all the classes that this template (V) accepts, inherit from a base class.  Can I somehow specify a lambda argument?

Comment: the code to insert an element in the map in unnecesasrily complicated. You can use `operator[]` to insert an element if it isnt present and get a reference to it, ie `itemsByTpye[ index].push_back(item);` is ok, whether there was an element for  `index` before or not. Actually I am curious where you saw this pattern for inserting into a map, I see it quite frequently and the right way is soo much simpler

Comment: *create a templated function* - W.E.Brown about [templated functions](https://youtu.be/NIDEjY5ywqU?t=203).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: it is a frequent idiom in others language which don't provide the equivalent of C++ interface. they can't "insert" a existing element.

Comment: @Jarod42 thats sounds like a reasonable explaination, I mean `map::operator[]` is a little odd when one isnt familiar with it but just `map::insert` is sufficient, and others, eg `set::insert` also work the same.

Comment: *"`getMapByType`"* I suggest to avoid name `get` for non-getter especially when complexity is not O(1). `makeMapByType` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: return of insert is powerful, but not simple. Most languages prefer simpler but less powerful interface (and so require 2 look-ups). Each language have their own idioms. :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Wasnt my intention to do language bashing, I just wondered, because I see this pattern with `std::map` rather frequently. Perhaps I am too much focused on a single language :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
have a pointer to a member fn as an extra parameter   
template<typename T, typename V>
std::map<T,std::vector<V>> getMapByType( const std::vector<V>& items, T (V::*fn)()const) {
  std::map<T,std::vector<V>> itemsByType;
  for( const auto& item : items ) {
    T index = (item.*fn)();
    auto it = itemsByType.find( index );
    if( it == itemsByType.end() ) {
      std::vector<V> v = { item };
      itemsByType.emplace( index, v );
    } else {
      it->second.push_back( item );
    }
  }
  return itemsByType;
}

auto res = getMapByType(items, &Category::getTab);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function that determines the key, something like this:

```
template <typename V,typename F>
auto getMapByType( const std::vector<V>& items,F func) {         
     using key_t = std::decay_t<delctype(func(item[0]))>;
     std::map<key_t,std::vector<V>> result;
     for (const auto& item : items) {
           result[ func(item) ].push_back(item);
     }
     return item;
}
```

Then you can call it like this

```
std:vector<Category> vec;
auto m = getMapByType( vec, [](const Category& c) { return c.getTab(); });
```

or

```
std:vector<Mode> vec;
auto m = getMapByType( vec, [](const Category& c) { return c.getType(); });
```

Note that `operator[]` does already what you reimplemented. It tries to find an element with the given key. If none is present it inserts a default constructed one, then it returns a reference to the mapped value.

Even without `operator[]` you do not need `find` and then `insert`, because `insert` does only insert when no element with given key was present. `insert` returns an iterator to the element and a `bool` which tells you if the insertion actually took place.

Comment: BTW, `func(item)` -> `std::invoke(func, item)`, so usage might also be `getMapByType(vec, &Category::getType);`

Comment: @Jarod42 uh nice, but thats something I'd like to understand myself before posting it in an answer ;)

Comment: the key_t can also use `std::invoke_result`